# Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData: Relative @odata.context Link for Service Document

Tags: asp.net-core, odata, reverse-proxy

Is there a way to control how the automatically generated `@odata.context`-URL is constructed by the service document handling Controller - without having to overwrite it with a custom implementation?

The current code creates one (custom-constructed) `EdmModel` which is passed to `routeBuilder.MapODataServiceRoute` as parameter. When accessing `/` the service document is automatically created by the Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData lib, with an `@odata.context`-link pointing to the metadata document. While running the service IIS-hosted (and thus receiving the full request URL) the auto-generated context-URL is correct. But once we try to put it into a container behind a reverse proxy (obviously) some parts of the path are missing, as the ASP.NET Core service is called by the reverse proxy with a new http request. Just returning this `@odata.context` would of course by incorrect.

Now, OData allows for *relative* URLs instead of absolute, which is great for this. But how can I tell `Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData` to create those?

For all other calls (entityset, single entity by id, function calls) I have custom controllers anyway, there I can just write relative URLs. But I hoped I could avoid writing the service document myself as well.

Comment: Similar problem here. Reverse proxy serves https but odata context contains http url (and different domain) and is causing PowerBI Connctor do fail. Any idea how to serve the publicly visible context url?

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to give an answers to feffe's comment, but couldn't due to reputation limitations, so this is slightly off-topic.

We solved the issue with $odata.context giving http urls while behind a proxy by adding the following middleware towards the top of Configure in our Startup file:

```
app.Use((context, next) =>
{
    context.Request.Scheme = "https";
    return next();
});
```

As is suggested by https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer?view=aspnetcore-5.0#when-it-isnt-possible-to-add-forwarded-headers-and-all-requests-are-secure.

A similar middleware could likely also solve OP's relative link issue by setting context.Request.Path accordingly.